# Can't reach Node server from Office Add-In

Tags: node.js, office-addins

I am making a Office Add-In and I am trying to reach my Node server, I enable CORS but still can't get it to work, please help:

Server code:

```
const server = Restify.createServer();
const port: string = process.env.port || process.env.PORT || "5512";
server.listen(process.env.port || process.env.PORT || 5512,  () => {
  console.log("Bot Server on port " + port);
});
server.use(Restify.plugins.bodyParser());
server.use(Restify.plugins.queryParser());
server.use(
    function crossOrigin(req, res, next) {
      res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
      return next();
    },
);
server.get("/", (req: Restify.Request, res: Restify.Response) => {
  res.send("AAE Relay Server is up.");
});
```

Office Add-In code:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        url: "https://server.azurewebsites.net/ping",
        data: JSON.stringify({...}),
        crossDomain: true,
        contentType: "application/json",

    })
    .done(function (data) {
        ...
    })
    .fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        ...
    })
    .always(function () {
        ...
    });
```

I am not getting any specific error, it just say "error".

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What's the error you're getting in-browser?

Comment: @Brad Sorry, should have clarified, this is from Office Add-In, I am not getting any error, just a generic "error".

Comment: Use a tool like Fiddler to get the full HTTPS request/response and post that so we can help you debug.

Comment: @Brad Ah nevermind, it turn out my URL is wrong, it actually did work.